# clone vm change network identity

Tags: powershell, clone, vmware, powercli

I'm trying to script (powershell/powercli) the cloning of our QA environment (261 servers).
Basically I want to make a new copy of each server just changing the VM name, the hostname, and the IP address. Ideally I'd want the new clone on the domain (90% of them are Windows OS). And many of my servers have many large hard drives that won't all fit on one datastore so I have to be able to clone to multiple datastores.

I started off with New-VM for the servers that were small enough to fit on one datastore, but OSCustomization only works about 30% of the time. The rest of the time I have to login to Windows and manually remove from the domain to rename the hostname. Most of the time Set-OSCustomizationNicMapping works But specifying -Domain -DomainUsername/Password never works (at best it renames the server and puts in the "domain-name" workgroup but it never joins it to the domain).

To workaround the multidatastore issue I discovered $vm.ExtensionData.CloneVM using VMWare.Vim.VirtualMachineRelocateSpec to specify which hard drives go to which datastores and that works great, but I don't know how to customize the hostname or NIC settings.

So the basic requirements are: clone to multiple datastores changing hostname and IP settings. Does anyone have any recommendations or solutions?

Here's some of my code snippets:

Setting up the OSCustomizationSpec for New-VM

```
$spec = New-OSCustomizationSpec -Name "PowerCLI Scripting for $NewHostName" -Spec "PowerCLI Scripting" -WhatIf:$False
Set-OSCustomizationSpec $spec -Workgroup "WORKGROUP" -DomainUsername "qajoin@qa.company.com" -DomainPassword (Get-Password -Username "qa\qajoin") -ProductKey $ProductKey -AdminPassword (Get-Password $Script:LuserName) | Out-Null
Get-OSCustomizationSpec "PowerCLI Scripting for $NewHostName" `
| Get-OSCustomizationNicMapping `
| Set-OSCustomizationNicMapping `
-IPMode:UseStaticIP `
-IPAddress $NewIPAddress `
-SubnetMask "255.255.248.0" `
-DNS "10.26.40.115","10.26.40.116" `
-DefaultGateway $NewDFGW | Out-Null
```

The New-VM command:

```
$VM = New-VM -VMHost $VMHost -VM $Hostname -Name $NewHostName -Description "$Description" -OSCustomizationSpec "PowerCLI Scripting for $NewHostName" -Location (Get-Folder -Id $Location) -Datastore $MostFreeSpace -ErrorAction Stop
```

Here's the multi-datastore clone:

```
$VMXtargetDatastore = Get-Datastore ($MapInfo | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "Hard disk 1"}).NewDataStore

#Create an empty CloneSpec
$spec = New-Object VMware.Vim.VirtualMachineCloneSpec 
$spec.Template = $false
 $spec.PowerOn = $false

 #Create a RelocateSpec (datastore is target for .vmx)
$spec.Location = New-Object VMware.Vim.VirtualMachineRelocateSpec
$spec.Location.Datastore = $targetDatastore.ExtensionData.MoRef

#For each disk in the current vm
#  create a new DiskLocator spec
#  populate the datastore and diskid from the current harddisk
#  add the spec to RelocateSpec from above
Get-HardDisk -VM $Origvm | %{
    $disk = New-Object VMware.Vim.VirtualMachineRelocateSpecDiskLocator
    $disk.diskId = $_.ExtensionData.Key #2001,2002,2003,...
    $DiskLabel = $_.ExtensionData.DeviceInfo.Label
    #$disk.datastore = $_.ExtensionData.Backing.Datastore #type=datastore value=datastore-2790
    $dsname = ($MapInfo | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $DiskLabel}).NewDataStore
    $ds = Get-Datastore -Name $dsname
    $disk.datastore = $ds.id
    $spec.Location.Disk += $disk
}

$CustSpec = New-Object VMware.Vim.CustomizationSpec
$origvm.ExtensionData.CloneVM((Get-Folder -Id $folder).ExtensionData.MoRef, $targetName, $spec)
```

I'm guessing the next step using the ExtensionData.CloneVM method is to declare a new object of CustomizationIdentitySettings but the documentation (http://pubs.vmware.com/vi3/sdk/ReferenceGuide/vim.vm.customization.IdentitySettings.html) that I could find isn't really helpful (probably because the settings vary by OS?) and then add that object to my $spec object.
Same would go for OSCustomizationNicMapping (http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/PowerCLI/PowerCLI41U1/html/OSCustomizationNicMapping.html) but I can't suss enough information out of the pubs to figure out how to build my $spec object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found this page: http://www.vmdev.info/?p=202
I started with the example they show and it worked, so I kept adding in CloneSpec fields until I got what I wanted:

```
    $nicMaparray = @()
    $FirstNic = New-Object VMware.Vim.CustomizationAdapterMapping
        $FirstNic.adapter = New-Object VMware.Vim.CustomizationIPSettings
            $FirstNic.adapter.dnsDomain = $domain
            $FirstNic.adapter.dnsServerList = "10.26.40.115","10.26.40.116"
            $FirstNic.adapter.gateway = $DefGW
            $FirstNic.adapter.ip = New-Object Vmware.Vim.CustomizationFixedIp
                $FirstNic.adapter.ip.IpAddress = $NewIP
            $FirstNic.adapter.subnetMask = "255.255.248.0"
    $nicMaparray += $FirstNic

    $folderobj = $origvm.parent
    $vm = Get-VM $sourceName | Get-View
    $cloneName = $targetName
    $cloneFolder = Convert-PathToFolderObject -FolderPath $folderpath
    $cloneSpec = new-object Vmware.Vim.VirtualMachineCloneSpec
    $cloneSpec.Location = new-object Vmware.Vim.VirtualMachineRelocateSpec
    $cloneSpec.Location.Host = (Random(Get-VMHost | Where {$_.Name -like "*esxiqa*"}) | get-view).MoRef
    $targetDatastore = ($MapInfo | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "Hard disk 1"}).NewDataStore
    $cloneSpec.Location.Datastore = (Get-Datastore $targetDatastore | get-view).MoRef
        $cloneSpec.customization = New-Object VMware.Vim.CustomizationSpec
            $cloneSpec.customization.globalIPSettings = New-Object VMware.Vim.CustomizationGlobalIPSettings
                $cloneSpec.customization.globalIPSettings.dnsServerList = "10.26.40.115","10.26.40.116"
            $cloneSpec.customization.identity = New-Object VMware.Vim.CustomizationSysprep
#           $spec.customization.identity.guiRunOnce = New-Object VMware.Vim.CustomizationGuiRunOnce
            $cloneSpec.customization.identity.guiUnattended = New-Object VMware.Vim.CustomizationGuiUnattended
                $cloneSpec.customization.identity.guiUnattended.autoLogonCount = 0
                $cloneSpec.customization.identity.guiUnattended.password = New-Object VMware.Vim.CustomizationPassword
                    $cloneSpec.customization.identity.guiUnattended.password.plainText = $true
                    $cloneSpec.customization.identity.guiUnattended.password.value = Get-Password -Username "Administrator"
            $cloneSpec.customization.identity.identification = New-Object VMware.Vim.CustomizationIdentification
                $cloneSpec.customization.identity.identification.joinWorkgroup = "WORKGROUP"
#           $spec.customization.identity.licenseFilePrintData = $null
            $cloneSpec.customization.identity.userData = New-Object VMware.Vim.CustomizationUserData
                $cloneSpec.customization.identity.userData.computerName = New-Object VMware.Vim.CustomizationFixedName
                    $cloneSpec.customization.identity.userData.computerName.name = $cloneName
                $cloneSpec.customization.identity.userData.productID = $ProductKey
            $cloneSpec.customization.nicSettingMap = $nicMaparray
                #nicMaparray build above
#           $cloneSpec.customization.options = $null
    $cloneSpec.powerOn = $true

    Get-HardDisk -VM $sourceName | %{
        $disk = New-Object VMware.Vim.VirtualMachineRelocateSpecDiskLocator
        $disk.diskId = $_.ExtensionData.Key #2001,2002,2003,...
        $DiskLabel = $_.ExtensionData.DeviceInfo.Label
        $dsname = ($MapInfo | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $DiskLabel}).NewDataStore
        $ds = Get-Datastore -Name $dsname
        $disk.datastore = $ds.id
        $cloneSpec.Location.Disk += $disk
    }

    Write-Verbose "Cloning $sourceName"
    try
    {
        $vm.CloneVM( $cloneFolder, $cloneName, $cloneSpec)
        return $true
    }
    catch
    {
        $_.Exception
        return $false
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you copy to an isolated environment? Just build a set of extra (isolated) VLANs and copy all VMs, keep IP/Names, only switch the VLAN at the VM level.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Unfortunately no I can't do an isolated environment, because of licensing and size issues some of my servers are single instance and the ones I'm cloning have to be able to route to the same single instances.

Comment: I build something like this for a big hospital. They needed a OTA environment in which they can have exact copies of their production VMs. I was not allowed to change the IP address of the VMs. I built a seperate VLAN in which I deployed the VMs and inserted the vShield Edge firewall as a NAT router. In this way the machines in the test environment could still access those servers. And their big cancer-treatment-scanner (which costs over a milion euro's) could not be copied of course, so I put an extra NAT router in front of it. Depending on scenario, it would route to prod or test.