# VMware VIM IPv6

Tags: powershell, vmware

This is based on this other post. 
[clone vm change network identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18276521/clone-vm-change-network-identity)

I need to set the IPv6 address when I build a VM.  I found the properties but it is not letting me set the value.

```
$FirstNic.Adapter.IpV6Spec = New-Object VMware.Vim.CustomizationIPSettingsIpV6AddressSpec 
$FirstNic.Adapter.IpV6Spec.Ip = New-Object VMware.Vim.CustomizationFixedIpV6 
$FirstNic.Adapter.IpV6Spec.Ip.IpAddress = "::1"

The property 'IpAddress' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set. At line:33 char:4 + $FirstNic.Adapter.IpV6Spec.Ip.IpAddress = "::1" + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

This is the members: TypeName: VMware.Vim.CustomizationFixedIpV6

```
Name    MemberType  Definition
----        ----------  ----------
Equals      Method      bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode     Method      int GetHashCode()
GetType     Method      type GetType()
ToString    Method      string ToString()
DynamicProperty Property    VMware.Vim.DynamicProperty[] DynamicProperty {get;set;}
DynamicType     Property    string DynamicType {get;set;}
IpAddress   Property    string IpAddress {get;set;}
SubnetMask  Property    int SubnetMask {get;set;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick testing indicates that setting that property on a `VMware.Vim.CustomizationFixedIpV6` directly seems to work. Assigning that to the `VMware.Vim.CustomizationIPSettingsIpV6AddressSpec` object after that seems to work also.

```
> $ip = New-Object vmware.vim.customizationfixedipv6
> $ip.IpAddress = "::1"
> $ipv6spec = new-object vmware.vim.customizationipsettingsipv6addressspec
> $ipv6spec.ip = $ip
> $ipv6spec.ip.ipaddress
::1
> $ipv6spec.ip.ipaddress = "::2"
Property 'ipaddress' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists and is settable
At line:1 char:1
+ $ipv6spec.ip.ipaddress = "::2"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException
```

However the `Ip` property of `VMware.Vim.CustomizationIPSettingsIpV6AddressSpec` doesn't seem to have `VMware.Vim.CustomizationFixedIpV6` as its type. It has `VMware.Vim.CustomizationIpV6Generator` instead.

So I wonder if this is a type specification/inheritance/etc. problem.

Comment: I got part of it to work which I will post.  But only the gateway show up.

Comment: $nic = New-Object VMware.Vim.CustomizationAdapterMapping
  $nic.Adapter = New-Object VMware.Vim.CustomizationIPSettings
  $nic.Adapter.ip = New-Object VMware.Vim.CustomizationFixedIp
  $nic.Adapter.ip.ipAddress = "192.168.1.$_"
   $nic.Adapter.subnetMask = "255.255.255.0"
   $nic.Adapter.IpV6Spec = New-Object vmware.Vim.CustomizationIPSettingsIpV6AddressSpec
   $nic.Adapter.ipV6Spec.Gateway = "::$_"
   $ipv6 = New-Object vmware.Vim.CustomizationFixedIpV6 
   $ipv6.IpAddress = "::$_"
   $ipv6.SubnetMask = 29
   $nic.Adapter.ipV6Spec.Ip = $ipv6
  $item.Spec.nicSettingMap += $nic

Comment: What do you mean? What's that code supposed to show me? Why is the IPv6 gateway the same as the IPv6 IpAddress?

Comment: Also, this seems like it might be a new question and you should mark this one as solved.